# Datanucleus autoCreateSchema issue (contradictory error messages)

Tags: java, h2, jdo, datanucleus

I have a small local H2 database whose content has been create with DataNucleus' JDO implementation. It contains a `rawcontainitem` table, associated to the following object:

```
@PersistenceCapable(objectIdClass=RawItemKey.class)
@Index(name="CONTAIN_IDX", members={"prefix", "language", "value"})
public class RawContainItem {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Column(length=40)
    String prefix = "";

    @PrimaryKey
    @Column(length=2)
    String language = "";

    @PrimaryKey
    @Column(length=Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    String value = "";    

    public RawContainItem(String prefix, String language, String value) {

        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.language = language;
        this.value = value;

    }

}
```

This table currently contains several rows where `language="FR"`. I want to add some more rows with `language="EN"`, but I get strange error messages.

When `datanucleus.autoCreateSchema` is set to `true`, I get:

```
INFO: Managing Persistence of Class : net.dwst.findword.DataNucleus.RawContainItem [Table : RAWCONTAINITEM, InheritanceStrategy : new-table]
23-mars-2012 14:42:49 org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable create
INFO: Creating table RAWCONTAINITEM
23-mars-2012 14:42:50 org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable executeDdlStatementList
GRAVE: Error thrown executing CREATE TABLE RAWCONTAINITEM
(
    "LANGUAGE" VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    PREFIX VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    "VALUE" VARCHAR(2147483647) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT RAWCONTAINITEM_PK PRIMARY KEY ("LANGUAGE",PREFIX,"VALUE")
) : Table "RAWCONTAINITEM" already exists; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE RAWCONTAINITEM
(
    "LANGUAGE" VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    PREFIX VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    "VALUE" VARCHAR(2147483647) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT RAWCONTAINITEM_PK PRIMARY KEY ("LANGUAGE",PREFIX,"VALUE")
) [42101-164]
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "RAWCONTAINITEM" already exists;
...
```

This message is true, the table exists indeed.

When `datanucleus.autoCreateSchema` is set to `false`, I get:

```
Required table missing : "RAWCONTAINITEM" in Catalog "" Schema "".
DataNucleus requires this table to perform its persistence operations.
Either your MetaData is incorrect, or you need to enable "datanucleus.autoCreateTables"
org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.exceptions.MissingTableException:
Required table missing : "RAWCONTAINITEM" in Catalog "" Schema "".
DataNucleus requires this table to perform its persistence operations.
Either your MetaData is incorrect, or you need to enable "datanucleus.autoCreateTables"
...
```

But the table does exists... What gives?

Comment: The problem is, the table "RAWCONTAINITEM" exists, but in a different catalog and schema. The catalog name is the name of the database, and the schema most likely "PUBLIC". But DataNucleus searches the table in the catalog "" (empty name) and schema "" (empty name). I just don't know how to tell DataNucleus to search in the default catalog and schema...

Comment: I'll take a look at this. I have not configured any catalog or schema. I was hoping leaving defaults would work. Thanks.